# Embedding structs to override methods

Tags: go

**TL;DR** See playground link at bottom.

I have methods defined on a `Manager` struct which contains a `Context`. The `Manager`s are versioned, allowing a new version to only define functions which have changed, and automatically use the functions from the old version if they are not redefined.

```
type Context struct { ... }

type Manager1 struct{
    Context Context
}

type Manager2 struct {
    Manager1
    Context Context
}
```

When calling a function on `Manager2` which is not defined on `Manager2` the `Context` is nil. Is there a way to do this where the context will be available?

This example demonstrates the problem better than I can explain it:
http://play.golang.org/p/gFe6GgUKEJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing embedding. The thing is, you've defined `Context` on `Manager1`, in spite of that you've redefined it on each subsequent type. In `Manager3` you're setting the value for it's `Context` instance. When `Hello()` is called, it's defined on `Manager2` and accesses it's `Context` instance which doesn't have a value. Check out this example to demonstrate that http://play.golang.org/p/XebShA9ap4

Money line is:
`m3 = Manager3{Manager2: Manager2{Context: Context{Value: "testing3"}}}`

As you can see, if I instantiate the `Manager2` instance embedded in `Manager3` and set it's `Context` value it gets printed. I would recommend changing your types so that `Context` is only defined on `Manager1` and then use syntax like that in my example when you initialize your types.

EDIT: To put the design discussed in comments in writing, you would change your types to this;

```
type Context struct {
    Value string
}

type Manager1 struct {
    Context Context
}

type Manager2 struct {
    Manager1
}

type Manager3 struct {
    Manager2
}
```

Delete the implementation of `Hello()` on `Manager2` altogether. Then update your composite-literal initialization to this;

```
m1 := Manager1{Context: Context{Value: "testing1"}}
m2 := Manager2{Manager1: Manager1{Context: Context{Value: "testing2"}}}
m3 := Manager3{Manager2: Manager2{Manager1: Manager1{Context: Context{Value: "testing3"}}}}
```

Comment: I would go so far as to say Manager2 and Manager3 should not contain context at all: https://play.golang.org/p/YkxjPZ4Hm6. Unless they need ot have unique values. But then they would all need to implement the function.

Comment: @captncraig yes I thought I made that point in the second to last paragraph. Maybe it wasn't clear. But yes, if `Manager1` has a `Context` instance, it would be a poor design to put that same field in anything that embeds `Manager1`. On top of being redundant it's god damned confusing!

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding calling methods of embedded  structs via the embedding struct: This is just syntactic sugar!

You are allowed to abbreviate `m3.Manager2.Hello()` to `m3.Hello()` but the Hello method is never invoked "on" m3 but always on the embedded `Manager2` (which has a nil Contex).

Embedding does not allow to "overwrite methods". Embedding is not subclassing, it is syntactic sugar only.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Manager3` struct contains a number of `Context` members - you're setting `Manager3.Context`, but printing `Manager2.Context`. What you're probably looking for is removing the redundant `Context` members from `Manager1` and `Manager2` and initializing the structs this way:

```
var (
    m1 = Manager1{Context: Context{Value: "testing1"}}
    m2 = Manager2{Manager1: Manager1{Context: Context{Value: "testing2"}}}
    m3 = Manager3{Manager2: Manager2{Manager1: Manager1{Context: Context{Value: "testing3"}}}}
)
```

Full example here: http://play.golang.org/p/13DOYKWN5C

Providing accessors or factory functions might make this a little nicer.